# How to change the background color of bootstrap-sweetalert?

Tags: laravel, sweetalert

What is the best way to change the background color of bootstrap-sweetalert ?
this is my code

```
.sweet-alert 
{
   background-color: #2f2f2f96;
}

$(".sweet-alert").css("background-color","#2f2f2f96");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

update your sweetalert.css with your coding and hard refresh your web browser. It should work.

```
.sweet-alert {
background-color: #2f2f2f96;
...other codings...
}
```

Comment: ah okay it worked now the problem is that i had this line in my css code .sweet-alert {
  background: url("../images/bg-pattern.png");
} when i erased it it worked nicely