# SweetAlert - Change modal color

Tags: javascript, css, sweetalert2

By default the colour is white.
Is it possible to change modal background color of sweetalert2?

I have tried it to change with CSS, as I follow on the other question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49365209/how-to-change-the-background-color-of-bootstrap-sweetalert) and [here](https://github.com/t4t5/sweetalert/issues/543#issuecomment-201126869), like this :

```
.sweet-alert 
{
   background-color: #2f2f2f96;
}
```

but I got nothing,

i use the sweetalert question feature

```
Swal.mixin({
  input: 'text',
  confirmButtonText: 'Next &rarr;',
  showCancelButton: true,
  progressSteps: ['1', '2', '3']
}).queue([
  {
    title: 'Question 1',
    text: 'Chaining swal2 modals is easy'
  },
  'Question 2',
  'Question 3'
]).then((result) => {
  if (result.value) {
    Swal.fire({
     title: 'All done!',
     html:
       'Your answers: <pre><code>' +
         JSON.stringify(result.value) +
        '</code></pre>',
      confirmButtonText: 'Lovely!'
    })
  }
})
```

I wish i can change the modal colour to grey

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to add **background**  in Swal function. It will Works for you.

```
Swal.mixin({
          input: "text",
          confirmButtonText: "Next &rarr;",
          showCancelButton: true,
          background: 'gray',
          progressSteps: ["1", "2", "3"]
        }) 
          .queue([
            {
              title: "Question 1",
              text: "Chaining swal2 modals is easy"
            },
            "Question 2",
            "Question 3"
          ])

          .then(result => {
            if (result.value) {
              Swal.fire({
                title: "All done!",
                 background: 'gray',
                html:
                  "Your answers: <pre><code>" +
                  JSON.stringify(result.value) +
                  "</code></pre>",
                confirmButtonText: "Lovely!"
              });
            }
          });
```

Comment: woahh, that work , I have read the documentation but I don't see that option, or whether I'm careless :D , thanks!